# How to Split the cell in itext?

Tags: java, itext

I need to split the cell into two by using iTextPDF. Like this below image in the table.

Here is the `Planned` cell I need to split into two cells

```
PdfPTable row4 = new PdfPTable(3);
row4.setWidthPercentage(100);
row4.setSpacingBefore(10);
row4.setSpacingAfter(10);

PdfPCell monday = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Monday ", tableheadres));
monday.setMinimumHeight(15f);
monday.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);

PdfPCell mondayvalue = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("social social,gfdgdf,fdfgfdg,fdgdfgfdsfsdfsd,ggdshgfgskfs,sggfsdfskjfjgshfjsgaf,shgjkfjk", tableval));
mondayvalue.setMinimumHeight(15f);
mondayvalue.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);

PdfPCell Planned = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Planned", tableheadres));
Planned.setMinimumHeight(15f);
Planned.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);

PdfPCell plansubstitue = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("social social,gfdgdf,fdfgfdg,fdgdfgfdsfsdfsd,ggdshgfgskfs,sggfsdfskjfjgshfjsgaf,shgjkfjk", tableval));

row4.addCell(monday);
row4.addCell(mondayvalue);

row4.addCell(Planned);
row4.addCell(plansubstitue);

document.add(row4);
```

Nested Code:

```
PdfPCell activity = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Activities / Approach / Introduction", tableheadres));
activity.setMinimumHeight(15f);
activity.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);
// activity.setRowspan(2);

PdfPTable activitynested = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell activitynestedcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nested Cell 1"));
activitynestedcell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
activity.addElement(activitynested);
```

Comment: As you used PdfPTable(3) it will create 3 columns change to this PdfPTable(4) then you will get the first row

Comment: how to create the nested table without removing the primary table content.

Comment: nested table in the sense give example

Comment: Can u check i have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not a good practice to dump the code this is the example of what you want :

```
public static void main(String arr[]) {
        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                    new FileOutputStream("TableNestedDemo.pdf"));
            document.open();
            PdfPTable row4 = new PdfPTable(4);
            row4.setWidthPercentage(100);
            row4.setSpacingBefore(10);
            row4.setSpacingAfter(10);

            PdfPCell monday = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Monday "));
            monday.setMinimumHeight(15f);
            monday.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);

            PdfPCell mondayvalue = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("social social,gfdgdf,fdfgfdg,fdgdfgfdsfsdfsd,ggdshgfgskfs,sggfsdfskjfjgshfjsgaf,shgjkfjk"));
            mondayvalue.setMinimumHeight(15f);
            mondayvalue.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);

            PdfPCell Planned = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Planned"));
            Planned.setMinimumHeight(15f);
            Planned.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);

            PdfPCell plansubstitue = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("social social,gfdgdf,fdfgfdg,fdgdfgfdsfsdfsd,ggdshgfgskfs,sggfsdfskjfjgshfjsgaf,shgjkfjk"));

            PdfPCell activity = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Activities / Approach / Introduction"));
            activity.setColspan(4);
            activity.setMinimumHeight(15f);
            activity.setLeading(0f, 1.2f);

            PdfPTable activitynested = new PdfPTable(1);
            PdfPCell activitynestedcell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nested Cell 1"));
            activitynestedcell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            activitynested.addCell(activitynestedcell);
            activity.addElement(activitynested);
            row4.addCell(monday);
            row4.addCell(mondayvalue);

            row4.addCell(Planned);
            row4.addCell(plansubstitue);
            row4.addCell(activity);

            document.add(row4);
            document.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```